# Less - Defining a class name that conflicts with mixin

Tags: css, less

The problem that I've got is quite simple. I want to use a css class name that has been previously defined as a mixin.

I'm currently using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which has defined a mixin called "placeholder", and because of backwards compatibility we're planning to use the [jQuery placeholder plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to support placeholders for IE 9. The problem is that this plugin adds the css class "placeholder" to the DOM element.

How do I define the css class "placeholder" in my LESS file without executing the mixin previously defined in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be a problem.  This is bootstrap's placeholder mixin

```
// Placeholder text
.placeholder(@color: @input-color-placeholder) {
  &:-moz-placeholder            { color: @color; } // Firefox 4-18
  &::-moz-placeholder           { color: @color;   // Firefox 19+
                              opacity: 1; } // See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11526
  &:-ms-input-placeholder       { color: @color; } // Internet Explorer 10+
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color: @color; } // Safari and Chrome
}
```

This is not a mixin class, as it has parenthesis after it.  Therfore it will not output anything unless it is referenced.  To use this I would need to do something like this.

```
.input {
    .placeholder;
}
```

Therefore this will not interfere with any `.placeholder` class you may have.

```
.placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

The two should happily co-exist and you should not get any problems.

**Edit: see comments**

The solution was to use multi class selector to overcome the issue.

**Example**

```
.input.placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's true if weren't for that I included the Bootstrap framework into my project (so I can fiddle with the variables.less). Now if I write a .placeholder css class it will effectively replace the Bootstrap mixin... Haven't found away around this yet, so in the meantime I'll bunde the LESS code with an external css containing the conflict.

Comment: Can you not use multiple class selector to resolve this problem.  e.g. `.input.placeholder { color: red }` This shouldn't effect your mixin.

Comment: Humm, though I had tried that... Well, that solved the problem, thank you for answering :-).

Comment: Well, mixins of the same name are not "replaced" but "merged" so `.placeholder {color: red}` will put `red` into every Bootstrap CSS class that calls `.placeholder` *in addition* to the initial Bootstrap properties. Not a big deal, `& .placeholder {color: red}` will create the same `.placeholder` class and hide it from Bootstrap.